# adapter addItem is not work in function

Tags: android, android-studio, android-adapter

```
public class TabBooklist extends Fragment {

/* <DB> */
//variable use in DB->
int nCount=1;
SQLiteDatabase db;
BookListDBHelper helper;
ListView listview ;
BookListShowAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_booklist, container, false);


    /* (XML) <Book list> */

    adapter = new BookListShowAdapter(getContext()) ;

    listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById (R.id.lv_book_list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.addItem(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_empty),
            "name1", "author1", 110, 1200) ; //work
    adapter.addItem(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_empty),
            "name21", "author21", 210, 1003) ; //work
    adapter.addItem(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),  R.drawable.ic_empty),
            "name31", "author31", 101, 1020) ; //work


    //refresh
    Button btn_ref = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh);
    btn_ref.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { //click to add
            select();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}


//select
public void select() {
    nCount = 1;

    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query("booklist", null, null, null, null, null, null);

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        int int_idBook = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id_book"));
        int int_idTree = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id_tree"));
        String str_title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title"));
        String str_author = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("author"));
        String str_imageLink = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("image_link"));
        int n_pageTotal = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("page_total"));

        //add
        adapter.addItem(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_empty),
                str_title, str_author, 0, n_pageTotal); //not work

        adapter.addItem(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_empty),
                "name31", "author31", 101, 1020) ; //not work

        nCount ++;
    }
}
}
```

I want to make that when if **click the refresh button** then **add item** to **list view.**
The `adapter.addItem` in `onCreateView function` is **work**.
But in `select function`, adapter.addItem is **not work**.
(And there is no error.)
The data is in the DB. (I checked it with the log)
Why `adapter.addItem` in `select function` is **not work** and what is the **solution**?

Comment: does nothing get added if you put in a dummy item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that

```
adapter.addItem(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_empty),
        "name1", "author1", 110, 1200) ; //work
adapter.addItem(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_empty),
        "name21", "author21", 210, 1003) ; //work
adapter.addItem(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),  R.drawable.ic_empty),
        "name31", "author31", 101, 1020) ; //work
```

works inside *onCreateView()* is because *onCreateView()* runs **before** your view is rendered, allowing the ListView to render the items.

However, in your *select()* method you are adding the items **after** the ListView has been rendered.

Because I do not know what your *BookListShowAdapter.addItem()* method looks like, I can only assume that you do not call *notifyDataSetChanged().* If you call this method at the end of *BookListShowAdapter.addItem()* method, your adapter will tell any view that reflects your data to refresh itself (which includes rendering).